# Parsing XML document Grouping Elements (some optional) in Oracle Database

Tags: xml, plsql, xml-parsing, oracle12c

I have the following scenario:
I have a xml file that contains an element with an unbounded complex type.

An example:

```
<Persons>
    <LastName>A</LastName>
    <FirstName>B</FirstName>
    <Age>1</Age>
    <LastName>C</LastName>
    <FirstName>D</FirstName>
    <Age>2</Age>
    <LastName>E</LastName>
    <FirstName>F</FirstName>
    <LastName>G</LastName>
    <FirstName>H</FirstName>
    <Age>4</Age>
</Persons>
```

As you can see, i have a Persons structure that contains a person definitions by repeating the structure:

```
   <LastName></LastName>
    <FirstName></FirstName>
    <Age></Age>
```

**The Age element is optional, so it may appear or in the xml document.**

I'm using a pl sql procedure in an Oracle Database 12c to process this xml message and then insert into some tables.

I tried using the XMLTABLE with some Xquery but i'm having difficulties on handling the optional values,is this case the **AGE element**.

Can someone give me a tip o help me solving this? Thanks a lot!!!

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Not optimal, but maybe useful:

description:

1. LastName always exists
2. 1st table for detection count of persons, you can use other ways
3. data extraction by position of sibling elements

sql:

```
select value( Persons ).extract( 'Persons/LastName[position()='||rownum||']/text()' ).getStringVal() LastName,
    value( Persons ).extract( 'Persons/LastName[position()='||rownum||']/following-sibling::*[position() = 1 and name() = ''FirstName'']/text()' ).getStringVal() FirstName,
    value( Persons ).extract( 'Persons/LastName[position()='||rownum||']/following-sibling::*[position() = 2 and name() = ''Age'']/text()' ).getNumberVal() Age
from table( xmlsequence( xmltype( '<Persons>
    <LastName>A</LastName>
    <FirstName>B</FirstName>
    <Age>1</Age>
    <LastName>C</LastName>
    <FirstName>D</FirstName>
    <Age>2</Age>
    <LastName>E</LastName>
    <FirstName>F</FirstName>
    <LastName>G</LastName>
    <FirstName>H</FirstName>
    <Age>4</Age>
</Persons>' ).extract( 'Persons/LastName' ) ) ) LastNames, table( xmlsequence( xmltype( '<Persons>
    <LastName>A</LastName>
    <FirstName>B</FirstName>
    <Age>1</Age>
    <LastName>C</LastName>
    <FirstName>D</FirstName>
    <Age>2</Age>
    <LastName>E</LastName>
    <FirstName>F</FirstName>
    <LastName>G</LastName>
    <FirstName>H</FirstName>
    <Age>4</Age>
</Persons>' ) ) ) Persons
```

Comment: Hi Hekko. Thanks for you comment and solution. It is useful and help me to solve my problem. I agree that is not optimal, but for my case is good enough. Thank you. Have a nice day.